# Regex - show directories , exclude frontpage

Tags: regex

How can I show some directories and exclude the frontpage "/"

The current code includes frontpage

```
^\/(app|page|create|examples|es)?($|\/).*
```

Pages I want to show

```
/app
/app/1231
/page
/page/abc
/create/1231
/es
/examples
/examples/abc/test
```

Pages I do not want to show

```
/  (frontpage)
/page-1231
/createabc
esda
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using

```
^\/(app|page|create|examples|es)(?:\/.*)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/iR1pSa/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `\/` - a slash
- `(app|page|create|examples|es)` - one of the alternative substrings
- `(?:\/.*)?` - an optional substring: `/` and any 0 or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.